# Modules and Lazy Loading Angular

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm working with Ionic and I have an IonicPage called Login with their respective files `(login.html, login.module.ts, login.scss, login.ts)`

Within the `login.module.ts` file I define in the array providers some `Provider` and `Service` files that I only use in Login, so I do not add them in the `app.module.ts` and this works very well for me

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpModule,
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage)
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    LoginPage
  ],
  providers: [
    settingsProvider,
    accessProvider,
    accessService
  ]
})
```

On the other hand I have a Module called `QuestionsModule` that is composed of 3 more modules, `Questions1Module`, `Questions2Module` and `Questions3Modules`

Where in the main module I have:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    Questions1Module,
    Questions2Module,
    Questions3Modules,
  ],
  providers: [
    questionService,
    questionProvider
  ]
})
export class QuestionsModule {}
```

From what I thought, when adding to the array of providers, the other imported modules could use my imported `Providers` and `Services`, but I am obliged, for example, in the Module of `Questions1Module` to add in the `@NgModule` again the declaration of the array Providers

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Questions1Page,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(Questions1Page),
  ],
  entryComponents: [
    Questions1Page
  ],
  providers: [
    questionService,
    questionProvider
  ]
})
```

If this is the right way to do it, what is the point of importing it 2 times in different parts to use the providers ?, another of my doubts is that in my `app.module.ts` within the array of imports I have declared:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  LoginModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, { mode: 'ios', backButtonText: '' }),
  HttpClientModule,
],
```

And if you see, it is not necessary for me to add `QuestionsModule`, but if LoginModule, if both are generated by IonicPageModule, why this difference?

Answer (score 0):

Better approach is to create file named like `shared.module.ts` and there you define the `questionService` and `questionProvider` or any other component,service,... that you will use more than once in 2 different modules,

**shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [],
   entryComponents: [],
   providers: [
      QuestionService,
      QuestionProvider
   ]
});
```

**Module where you want to use something from the shared.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      Questions1Page
   ],
   imports: [
      IonicPageModule.forChild(Questions1Page),
      SharedModule // this module will import the QuestionService and other..
   ],
   entryComponents: [
      Questions1Page
   ],
   providers: []
});
```

Comment: I understand, but what is the use of my QuestionsModule and the providers that I declare there, for my other QuestionsXModule?, What I do not understand is because I do not have to import Questions Module in my AppModule, not with my LoginModule that I must import it.

Comment: Because you are propably not using something from QuestionsModule in the AppModule "scope". You would need that to import it there only, if for example the app.components.ts used the service from the QuestionsModule...

Comment: I happen to import Questions Module in AppModule and my other Modules, (Question1Module ...) now if they can use the providers without needing to import them ... what will it be?

Comment: It should work, because AppModule is on the TOP of the all modules, But I don't recommend this approach, in larger project you wouldn't be happy, to see that all modules, components, services,... are imported/declared in the app.module.ts. Also if you split it into a more modules, debugging will be also easier :)

Comment: I still do not understand how ionicModulePage works and the import of Modules inside a Module